# A course on Logic.

Tags: reference-request, logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, higher-order-logic

I'm looking for a selection of books, in order to properly learn logic, starting from the most basic principles of propositional calculus and going up the ladder, up to higher order logic.

My number one priority is formality and rigorousity.

What are some good books on the subject?

Comment: As one of the answers has it, Peter Smith is an excellent teacher of logic. Unfortunately, he doesn't have a freely available introduction to logic, but after you get the foundations (up to the compactness and completeness theorem for first-order logic), you should definitely read his book "Godel without tears".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Peter Smith](http://www.logicmatters.net/about/) (a former lecturer in philosophy at such notable institutions as the Universities of Sheffield, Aberystwyth and Cambridge) has [an extensive, annotated list](http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/) of good books. You might want to take a look through that list. He accounts for the needs of mathematicians quite explicitly.

Comment: agreed. I've started reading the first book on that list, *Mathematical Logic* by Ian Chiswell, and it's a good introduction to a more rigorous treatise of logic.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Logic as Algebra (Dolciani Mathematical Expositions)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883853272) by Paul Halmos and Steven Givant.

> Here is an introduction to modern logic that differs from others by treating logic from an algebraic perspective. What this means is that notions and results from logic become much easier to understand when seen from a familiar standpoint of algebra. The presentation, written in the engaging and provocative style that is the hallmark of Paul Halmos, from whose course the book is taken, is aimed at a broad audience, students, teachers and amateurs in mathematics, philosophy, computer science, linguistics and engineering; they all have to get to grips with logic at some stage. All that is needed to understand the book is some basic acquaintance with algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Discrete Mathematics and Its Application by Rosen might help. I used this when the first time I learnt about logic. My second option is Discrete Mathematics: Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning by Susanna Epp. Hope this helps. Cheers!